# Meta showing same reputation as Stack Overflow when visited in mobile app

Tags: support, reputation, meta, android-app, ios-app

Using the Stack Exchange mobile app, when I switched to Meta and asked a question over there, it is showing the same reputation as on Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a bug - your reputation on the main site is "mirrored" on Meta. See the [help center](/help/whats-meta):

> your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly)

You should see this behaviour in your browser as well.